# how to reduce the size of and locatin of image integrated with input field?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, html5-canvas

I want a button overlapped on input field in responsive website just like this :
[image]

for this i used an input group addons but that gives me result as follow :
[image]

and that is because of size of image so how can i bring input field in mid of button and reduce it's size to obtain output as per above image?

Code is here:

```
<div class="input-group ">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <img src="./images/record.png">
            </span>
            <input type="text" size="1" class="form-control" placeholder="REC" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position:absolute` on img tag and vertically center by adding `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`

```css
 .input-group-image {
    z-index: 4
}

.input-group-image img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 60px;
    top: 50%; /* moves 50% from top */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* to vertically center the image */
}

.input-group .input-group-control {
    padding-left: 70px; /* to add space between image and input box  */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group ">
   <span class="input-group-prepend input-group-image">
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TS5W.png">
   </span>
   <input type="text" size="1" class="form-control input-group-control" placeholder="REC" />
 </div>
```

Comment: i tried that and even i also reduce the size of the input field but it got separated when trying to open it in other window size such as phone

Comment: add this .input-group-image {z-index: 4} . since form-control has z-index: 3 when it is in focus state.

Comment: it' working perfectly but can you please explain a bit how this is happening and input block size is not reduced a bit